# How to add programs in the right click buton on 2003 server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

How do I add a command like disk cleanup on the right click of the mouse button on Windows 2003 Server without modifying the registry?

Comment: That is registry dependent, don't think it can be done without modifying the registry.